# Sublime build - dynamic file name

Tags: sublimetext2, bibtex

I need to make a build file for BibTeX files.

I have the following:

```
{
  "cmd": ["bibtex", "*.aux"],
  "selector": "text.bibtex"
}
```

When I run `bibtex *.aux` from terminal, it works fine. However, sublime keeps telling me:

```
I couldn't open file name `*.aux'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: make a custom script!

eg: `subl /home/user/buildBibtex.sh` consisting of:

```
#!/bin/sh
bibtex *.aux
```

run `chmod +x /home/user/buildBibtex.sh`

and the build file will look like this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["/home/user/buildBibtex.sh"],
  "selector": "text.bibtex"
}
```